# Dynamic char array from class dont printing the proper result

Tags: c++, class, oop, dynamic, char

i am making a project in which user will add the info of car and one function will show all the available cars.But the i cannot be able to copy names of car from one array to another here is the code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE=10;

class car
{
   public:
int car_no=0;
char car_name[SIZE][20];
char car_model[SIZE][20];
char car_colour[SIZE][20];
char reg_id[SIZE][20];
int rate_per_day[SIZE];
char cars_in_lot[SIZE][20];
};

addcar()
{
    char choice;
    do{

   car*newcar=new car;

    cout<<"\t\t\t\t(->)  Name : ";
    cin>>newcar->car_name[newcar->car_no];
    strcpy(newcar->cars_in_lot[newcar->car_no],newcar->car_name[newcar->car_no]);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t(->)  reg!str@t!0n number : ";
    cin>>newcar->reg_id[newcar->car_no];
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t(->)  c0l0ur : ";
    cin>>newcar->car_colour[newcar->car_no];
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t(->)  Model : ";
    cin>>newcar->car_model[newcar->car_no];
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t(->)  Rate of Rent Per Day : ";
    cin>>newcar->rate_per_day[newcar->car_no];
    newcar->car_no++;
    cout<<"Want to add another car [y/n]"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    }while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

}
void show_cars_in_lot()
 {
      cout<<"Avaialable Cars in Lot are : "<<endl;
      car*newcar=new car;
      for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
      cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<newcar->cars_in_lot[i]<<"\t"<<newcar->car_colour[i]     <<"\t"<<newcar->car_model[i]<<"\t"<<newcar->reg_id[i]<<endl;
getch();
}

void display1()
  {

cout<<"\t\t\t(1)  Show Cars in Lot"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t(2)  Add Cars"<<endl;
 }// end of display1

int main()
 {
  char option;
  int desire_car;
do
{
    int choice;
    display1();
    cout<<"Enter Your Choice : ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        show_cars_in_lot();break;
    case 2:
        addcar();break;
    default:
    cout<<"You Entered Wrong Input"<<endl;
    }
cout<<"Go To Main Menu [y/n]";cin>>option;
}while(option == 'y' || option == 'Y');

return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Use `std::string` to make your life easier.

Comment: Also use a debugger to make your life even easier.

Comment: Because you add cars to one object (`car*newcar=new car;` in `addcar()`) but attempt to display from another (`car*newcar=new car;` in `show_cars_in_lot()`). Use `new` only to allocate memory for new instance. Probably you don't need to use `new` in `show_cars_in_lot()`

Comment: @kay27 program not runn if i dont write new in show_cars_in_lot

Comment: so, this way program runs, but doesn't work... you need to use your existing object in `show_cars_in_lot()`, you don't have to create another one. how to use it: there are so many ways. eg. use `new` only once - in main() and save pointer somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you change your data structure to a container of car properties, instead of a single structure of arrays.

```
struct Car_Properties
{
  public:
    int         number;
    std::string name;
    std::string model;
    std::string colour;
    std::string reg_id;
    int         rate_per_day;
    std::string cars_in_lot;
};
std::vector<Car_Properties> car_inventory;
// Or  
Car_Properties car_lot[SIZE];
```

In general, the above is more efficient because the car properties (for a single car) are contiguous in memory.

Note:  When using `std::vector`, there is no need to use the `new` operator.  The `std::vector` will make a copy.  You will want to implement a copy constructor and assignment operators.  Reminder:  Also overload operators `==` and `<`.

**Edit 1: Creating a Car_Properties dynamically**
The easiest method is just to declare an instance of the variable:

```
int main()
{
  Car_Properties das_auto; // This creates an instance in local memory.
  //...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want to read car properties from a file, you can overload the object to read its members:

```
struct Car_Properties
{
  public:  
    void load_by_prompting(std::istream& input,
                           std::ostream& output);
  //...
}

void
Car_Properties ::
load_by_prompting(std::istream& input,
                  std::ostream& output)
{
  output << "Enter car number: ";
  input >> number;
  output << "Enter car name: ";
  std::getline(input, name);
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  Car_Properties das_auto;

  // Input data into the variable
  das_auto.load_by_prompting(std::cin, std::cout);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i make the object of car dynamically

Comment: @AhsanAli: See my Edit 1.